# import/export data from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Hi guys i am making an application for iPhone that will allow user to access server and pull data thorught NSUrl request and store it in phone memory. Then user won't be able to access the internet( may be somewhere out where there is no internet connection) and when he comes back in the coverage will be able to submit the store data back to server.( user has made some change while he was away and didn't had any internet connection) all the time.

So what will be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a HTTP connection you mentioned. While the user is offline, you can store the data using Core Data. When the user is back you send a HTTP POST/PUT request to upload the data back to the server.

For easy HTTP requests on the iPhone use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).